# Variable recording event incrementally (no loops)

Tags: matrix, stata

I have this kind of structure (`ID` and `Event`) :

```
ID    Event    X
A       0      0
A       0      0
A       1      1
A       0      1
B       0      0
B       1      1
B       0      1
B       1      2
B       0      2
B       0      2
B       1      3
```

And I would like to create `X`, but I can't use any loops as the data base is huge. I would appreciate any suggestion.

Edit: I tried some kinds of `bysort ID` and `Event` without luck:  now I'm working with this approach:

```
gen Spell=Event 

replace Spell=2 if Spell[_n-1]==1 & Spell[_n+1]==0 & ID[_n]==ID[_n-1]
```

but it's not going to work since I can't discriminate between the second or the third + event showing on the data base.

***Solved***

```
gen X=Event[_n]
replace X=X[_n]+X[_n-1] if _n>1 & ID[_n]==ID[_n-1]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? Please edit your question to show the code of your attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Datasets like this need a time or other sequence variable. You should certainly create one if you don't have one:

```
sort ID, stable 
by ID : gen t = _n
```

What you want is then just

```
bysort ID (t) : gen wanted = sum(event)
```

which is cleaner and clearer than what you have. In Stata

```
help sum() 
search by 
search spell
```

to see relevant help files and expository articles.

(You are aware of this approach, but as you don't show precisely what you tried, so we can't comment on what was wrong.)